# Tkinter Window Background Color Not Working On MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

Tkinter window background color does not change from black to white on my MacBook Air, but does work on my Windows 10 main PC. I am using the Pycharm Community Edition as me IDE.

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.configure(bg = "white")
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue on a 16" M2 Pro MacBook Pro.

Answer (score 0):

you have spelled wrong tkinter in the first line.

Comment: That was just a typo when I typed the code in stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading my Python to the latest version (i.e., 3.11 at the time of writing) fixed the issue for me.

I'm using a 16" M2 Pro MacBook Pro.